# Colorful Subgraph Dynamic Programming Solution and a Naive One

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity

Given a graph `G(V, E)` with vertices `V` and edges `E`, where each vertex is associated with a single color from a set of colors `C={1, 2, ..., k}`, we define the following problem:

#### Problem Statement:

- **Input**: A graph `G(V, E)` and a set of colors `C`, with a constraint that each vertex `v` in `V` is assigned exactly one color from `C`.
- **Objective**: Determine if there exists a connected subgraph of `G` that is "C-colorful". A subgraph is considered "C-colorful" if it contains exactly one vertex of each color present in `C`.

#### Background:

Topology-Free Querying of Protein Interaction Networks
SHARON BRUCKNER et al. (2010, Journal of Computational biology)

#### Complexity:

The problem has been proven to be NP-complete, the authors say there is a solution using Dynamic Programming that is `O(3^k * |E|)`

#### Example Inputs:

```py
example_input = {
    "vertices": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    "edges": [
        ("v1", "v2"),
        ("v2", "v3"),
        ("v3", "v4"),
        ("v4", "v5"),
        ("v1", "v3"),
        ("v2", "v4"),
    ],
    "color_constraints": {"v1": 1, "v2": 2, "v3": 3, "v4": 1, "v5": 2},
    "num_colors": 3,
}  # Should be True

example_input_2 = {
    "vertices": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    "edges": [
        ("v1", "v2"),
        ("v2", "v3"),
        ("v3", "v4"),
        ("v4", "v5"),
        ("v1", "v3"),
        ("v2", "v4"),
    ],
    "color_constraints": {"v1": 2, "v2": 1, "v3": 1, "v4": 1, "v5": 3},
    "num_colors": 3,
}  # Should be False

example_input_3 = {
    "vertices": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    "edges": [
        ("v1", "v2"),
        ("v2", "v3"),
        ("v3", "v4"),
        ("v4", "v5"),
        ("v1", "v3"),
        ("v2", "v4"),
    ],
    "color_constraints": {"v1": 2, "v2": 1, "v3": 1, "v4": 2, "v5": 3},
    "num_colors": 3,
}  # should be True
```

#### My implementation of the authors' DP solution

```py
from itertools import combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    list_all_combinations = []
    for r in range(len(s)+1):
        list_all_combinations += list(combinations(s, r))
    return list_all_combinations
# powerset([1, 2, 3]) -> [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]

def find_colorful_subtree(graph_info) -> bool:
    """
    graph_info is a dictionary which keys are 'vertices', 'edges', 'color_constraints', and 'num_colors' and values are
    dictionaries.
    """
    vertices: list[str]
    edges: list[tuple[str, str]]
    vertices, edges = graph_info['vertices'], graph_info['edges']
    v_to_idx: dict[str, int] = {v: idx for idx, v in enumerate(vertices)}  # idx_to_v is not needed, it's vertices
    color_map: dict[str, int] = graph_info['color_constraints']
    num_colors: int = graph_info['num_colors']
    
    # Create graph
    g = {v: set() for v in vertices}
    for u, v in edges:
        g[u].add(v)
        g[v].add(u)
    
    # DP table dp[v][S] = True if a subtree rooted at v is S-colorful
    # We encode S with integers (bitmask) 
    dp = [[False for _ in range(1 << num_colors)] for _ in range(len(vertices))]

    # Initialize the DP table
    for v_idx, v in enumerate(vertices):
        color = color_map[v]
        dp[v_idx][1 << color - 1] = True
    
    # Recursive function to fill the DP table
    for subset in powerset(range(num_colors)):
        if len(subset) <= 1:
            continue
        # generate all s1, s2 such that s1 + s2 = subset and s1 & s2 = {}
        s: int = 0
        for color in subset:
            s |= 1 << color
        for left_subset in powerset(subset):
            if len(left_subset) == 0 or len(left_subset) == len(subset):
                continue
            left_mask: int = 0
            for color in left_subset:
                left_mask |= 1 << color
            right_mask: int = s ^ left_mask  # ^ -> XOR

            for v_idx, v in enumerate(vertices):
                if (1 << color_map[v] - 1) & left_mask != 0:
                    for u in g[v]:
                        if (1 << color_map[u] - 1) & right_mask == 0:
                            continue
                        if dp[v_idx][left_mask] and dp[v_to_idx[u]][right_mask]:
                            dp[v_idx][s] = True
                            break  # no need to check other neighbors, we found a colorful subtree rooted at v
            
    ans: bool = False
    for v_idx, v in enumerate(vertices):
        ans |= dp[v_idx][(1 << num_colors) - 1]
    
    return ans

# Running the algorithm on the examples
assert find_colorful_subtree(example_input)
assert not find_colorful_subtree(example_input_2)
assert find_colorful_subtree(example_input_3)
```

#### A naive implementation in complexity `O(2^|V| * |V|)`

```py
def find_colorful_subtree_naive(graph_info) -> bool:
    """
    graph_info is a dictionary which keys are 'vertices', 'edges', 'color_constraints', and 'num_colors' and values are
    dictionaries.
    """
    vertices: list[str]
    edges: list[tuple[str, str]]
    vertices, edges = graph_info['vertices'], graph_info['edges']
    v_to_idx: dict[str, int] = {v: idx for idx, v in enumerate(vertices)}  # idx_to_v is not needed, it's vertices
    color_map: dict[str, int] = graph_info['color_constraints']
    num_colors: int = graph_info['num_colors']
    
    # Create graph
    g = {v: set() for v in vertices}
    for u, v in edges:
        g[u].add(v)
        g[v].add(u)
    
    # we take a set of vertices (2^(|V|)) and check if it is colorful (O(|V|))
    for s in range(1 << len(vertices)):
        if bin(s).count('1') < num_colors:
            continue
        # Check if the set is colorful
        colors: set[int] = set()
        for v_idx, v in enumerate(vertices):
            if (1 << v_idx) & s:
                if color_map[v] in colors:
                    break
                colors.add(color_map[v])
        if len(colors) == num_colors:
            # Check if the set of vertices is connected
            visited: set[str] = set()

            def dfs(v: str):
                visited.add(v)
                for u in g[v]:
                    if u not in visited and (1 << v_to_idx[u]) & s:
                        dfs(u)

            for v_idx, v in enumerate(vertices):
                if (1 << v_idx) & s:
                    dfs(v)
                    break
                    
            if len(visited) == bin(s).count('1'):
                return True

    return False


# Running the algorithm on the examples
assert find_colorful_subtree_naive(example_input)
assert not find_colorful_subtree_naive(example_input_2)
assert find_colorful_subtree_naive(example_input_3)
```

Are there things I could improve for my implementations? Are there things I got wrong?

Comment: I'm new to this StackExchange I hope this post follows the rules.

Comment: You're doing fine. But when you say **... where each vertex is associated with a unique color from a set of colors ...**, don't you mean that each vertex is associated with a *single* color from a set of colors? To me the word "unique" suggests that no color is duplicated on another vertex. But maybe I am reading the wrong interpretation.

Comment: Oh yes, single works too and is less ambiguous. I didn't mean to say that no colour was duplicated on another vertex.